# Stepper motor refuses to turn

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor

I have a NEMA 23 Bipolar stepper motor ([specsheet](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/23HS45-4204S.pdf)) connected to a 24V 6A power supply that is connected to a driver (DM542T) and an Arduino Uno. I have it wired exactly as the specsheet entails: blue, red, green, black connected to B-, B+, A-, A+ for each coil respectively. Using the following code:

```
// Defin pins

int reverseSwitch = 2;  // Push button for reverse
int driverPUL = 7;    // PUL- pin
int driverDIR = 6;    // DIR- pin
int spd = A0;     // Potentiometer

// Variables

int pd = 500;       // Pulse Delay period
boolean setdir = LOW; // Set Direction

// Interrupt Handler

void revmotor (){

  setdir = !setdir;
  
}


void setup() {

  pinMode (driverPUL, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (driverDIR, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(reverseSwitch), revmotor, FALLING);
  
}

void loop() {
  
    pd = map((analogRead(spd)),0,1023,2000,50);
    digitalWrite(driverDIR,setdir);
    digitalWrite(driverPUL,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(pd);
    digitalWrite(driverPUL,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(pd);
 
}
```

Results in only the motor vibrating and not turning. I doubled checked all the connections and used a different Arduino as well. Why is this occurring? My initial thoughts were a bad driver or (less likely) a bad motor but I ordered a new one and got the same results so obviously, the problem is on my end. I have been stuck on this for a few days now. Any thoughts?

I'd like mention I have used the Arduino's stepper library as well to no avail.

Comment: Does this compile,correctly?  I think your line... boolean setdir = LOW;  ...should generate an error.  Variable type should be "bool", not "boolean".

Comment: you already asked this ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/89327/stepper-motor-only-vibrates-does-not-move ... please fix up that question, instead of posting this one

Comment: One common cause of step motor trembling is wrong step rate.  delayMicroseconds(500) = 2kHz.  I would suggest to try higher step rates up to 5kHz. I once found 5kHz work for one of my steppers, but no luck if less than 3k5Hz.

Comment: @GTElectronics it indeed compiles, I have used the AccelStepper library as well, same results

Comment: @jsotola do you just go through peoples profile accts to point out crappy tips like that?

Comment: If connected correctly, you should have high static holding torque.  But I would swap out your code with compiled Gcode for a CNC shield then download Gcode Panel for Windows. Open source very slick interfaces and features like g max, v max, home button and jog XY

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 yes, that’s my problem. Clearly current is running through the coils as it’s nearly impossible to turn when charged. I will try that thanks

Comment: @thediyert no, I remember seeing your first post